# Is it possible to have a duplicate in Code Review?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do we define duplicate questions?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-do-we-define-duplicate-questions)

In other stackexchange sites, questions like:

```
What is the use of Models in MVC?
Why should we use Models in MVC?
```

may be closed down since they are so alike. However, in Code Review - questions like:

```
Please review my response class.
Please review my response class.
```

might not be duplicate at all, since they might be posting different classes. It might be similar, it might be very different, and no matter how similar both code is, if there is a difference, then it's not the same code and the answers for one might not apply to the other.

How do you gauge whether or not is it a duplicate in Code Review? I wanted to post my class in code review for comments, but I am afraid of getting voted down.

Thanks for the sites.

---

UPDATE

After reading for a while, I think I kinda get it. If my code is similar to the one already posted, I should just post the differences.

But I still think Code Review is quite different from other stack exchange site and should probably have rules that differs a bit. I still can't pinpoint the problem is, and example is this, when I try to create a question titled `First try in Response class, let me know what you think.`, this comes up:

```
"The question you are asking appears to be subjective and is likely to be closed."
```

It's not a wording problem, since I tried `What do you think of my response class?` and it's rebuked too. I think this is ridiculous. Code Review is a site to ask for peer reviews right? Why am I not allowed to ask for other people's opinions (criticisms, feedback) on the class I just wrote? Or am I misunderstanding Code Review?

---

UPDATE

The way I see is, Code Review isn't a Q/A site like stack overflow or stack exchange is. In a Q/A site, you ask when you have a problem. In a site for peer-reviewing like Code Exchange, you **don't** have a problem. You just want to get some feedback, criticisms, suggestions, and learn from them. In fact, if you already identified a problem, you wouldn't post it in Code Review, you would've tried to solve it, or asked about it in stackoverflow.com. It's because *you don't know what problem your code might have* that you want it to be peer-reviewed. This is why, I think, Code Review is not a Q/A site, and therefore, cannot be effectively managed with the same rules as other stackexchange sites.

Comment: I like how this is a meta-duplicate meta duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Closing as duplicate is done manually.

if it is not a real duplicate, they will not close it duplicate.

or the question title need to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thing about Code Review is, it's not exactly a Q/A site. It's a site for people to have their code peer-reviewed. This means the question can be as broad as just asking for feedback, no matter what it is. So making the question more specific is not an option. If you can make the question more specific, it wouldn't be asking for peer-review, right? It would be asking for something like, 'Is this piece of code memory intensive?' - which would be better asked in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @rickchristie, you might be correct about those should be allowed in CR, but the msg you're getting is from unintelligent regex match to your title something like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work) in stack overflow (CR might have deifferent keywords there)- you may not need to worry about that much about those msg there, IMHO.

Comment: @YOU - thanks for the link, have you read the another update of the question that I made? What do you think about it?

Comment: @rickchristie, agreed, you may request them for what kind of subjective filtering they did on CR, and/or you may ask them to update the algorithm, in another question. I hope they might understand your logic.