# Gold tag-badge users closing questions as pre-written off-topic duplicates

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

I often see questions which are blatantly **off-topic**, like, for instance, when [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100667/what-if-the-catch-block-is-empty) (can only be viewed with enough rep, as it has been deleted) showed up.

The shown [c#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23) code had been

```
try
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c=a+b;
}
catch (exception ex)
{
//Nothing here    
}
```

Which is, for sure, example code and won't even compile.

If, on the main site we would:

1. Create questions for **off-topic** reasons like containing example code.
2. Add an answer stating **why** this is off-topic
3. [Lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) the question and comment.

We could benefit as community, if a gold tag-badge user could then mark such questions, like mentioned above, as duplicate of one of the off topic questions.

Comment: Your heart's in the right place, but I don't like this because it means we need at least several off topic questions left open.

Comment: @RubberDuck no not necessarily...

Comment: [Legal fictions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_fiction) tend to create all kinds of problems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### No

"Duplicate" on Code Review has a special meaning (the code is exactly the same)... and that's hard enough to keep clarity on as it is. Adding a special case where some things that are completely different, are also duplicates, would be a problem.

Additionally, some people will be voting to close the question as off-topic-example-code, and others as duplicates.

The better solution would be to give gold-tag-badge holders more weight with off-topic close votes.

Answer (score 8):

If a question is off-topic, the tags don't necessarily make sense. For example, there may not be any language tags on the question at all. While the requirement to have a gold badge in such tags could work in a majority of cases, it isn't necessarily the optimum.

I smell a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/269301) here. There are off-topic posts which we need to close and your approach is stamping Duplicate on them if they're broken. But we already got a perfectly fine close reason for that. Yes, that needs 5 people (or a moderator) instead of 1. But is that a problem? We have very active moderators lurking in [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) who can hammer questions shut and regulars who can flag/vote if need be.

This also smells like an awful lot of extra work to get the same thing done. Instead of letting 5 users making a simple vote, you'll ask 1 user to find which question it's a duplicate of. Finding a duplicate target is more time consuming than a simple close vote and more error prone.

Finally this would also open a can of worms. While [Mjölnir](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254590/1014587) is overall a success, it has it's limitations and drawbacks. Implementing your proposal would have to be done very carefully and under constant watch by the SE team and/or the moderators.

Implementation of this proposal may also lead to a shift in our ["a question is almost never a duplicate"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3821/52915) policy.

Answer (score 8):

## No.

The structure you're talking about exists (*for some values of exists*) in Area 51 during Site Definition, however, in graduated sites, has no place.

1. Creating off-topic posts are bad on users' parts, and bad for the site.
2. Answering off-topic posts, *not even with Code Reviewing, but with 'This is off-topic'*, is both not an answer, and would recieve my flag/downvote.
3. There are thirteen gold-tag-badge users, of which, four are moderatiors (and rolfl), meaning this purpose is very niche.
4. Posts may hit the deletion queue without being noticed (*theoretically, if the mods weren't so gosh darn responsive :D*), and get removed entirely.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree about marking them as duplicated.

I highly doubt there will be an off-topic duplicated question. If there was, there's a simple way to deal with that:

- If it is duplicated, mark as such
- If you can't find the original (deleted or something), mark as off-topic.

Now, about allowing users with gold badges to mark such questions as off-topic and hammer them, I totally agree!

Comment: Yeah, losing track of duplicate posts is a pain in the neck, many a meta asker has felt the sting of duplication, despite searching beforehand.