# Where should I explain why I think one question is not a dupe to another?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I first posted question: [Allowing switching between operator[] and at() based on NDEBUG](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158078/allowing-switching-between-operator-and-at-based-on-ndebug)
Then I posted question: [Allowing switching between operator[] and at() based on NDEBUG macro version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158082/allowing-switching-between-operator-and-at-based-on-ndebug-macro-version)

Someone marked the second question a dupe to the first one. I was shown a large box prompting me to edit my question if I think it was not a dupe, explaining in detail the differences. So I did.

But this edit was subsequently [reverted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/158082/revisions) by a mod, because “*Meta notes don't belong in the question itself*”.

I’m confused. Shouldn't the box that is shown to the OP whenever their question gets dupe-marked be edited?

Comment: *This* Meta sight would be the best place.  You can post the questions and explain why they're not duplicates.  You can also read [this](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-do-we-define-duplicate-questions).